# Getting square matrix of dimension matrixrank

Tags: matrix, manipulate

I have matrix with dimensions {24,33} and matrix rank 23, it is symbolic. Is there a way to get matrix with dimension {23,23} by using built-in Mathematica functions? I would know how to get it simple..by taking one by one row which increases rank and than transpose it and do the same again. Is there a easier way?

Comment: Could you post a smaller example? Lest say with a 5x3 matrix.

Comment: best I could think of..but with numbers. so I need to get mat1 from mat2. thanx

mat1 = Table[RandomInteger[100], {ii, 1, 3}, {jj, 1, 3}];

mat2 = Append[mat1, mat1[[3]]];
mat2 = Transpose[mat2];
mat2 = Join[mat2, {mat2[[1]] + mat2[[3]], mat2[[2]] - mat2[[3]]}];
mat2 = Transpose[mat2];

Comment: What is the relation between the {24,33} and {23,23} matrix?

Comment: I fully concur with the @DanielHuber comment. You have to say how the resulting `{23,23}` matrix should be related to the initial  `{24,33}` matrix.

Comment: long story, I got bigger matrix from homogenous system of linear equations, it is overdetermined, I need to calculate its determinant and it has to square matrix.

Comment: Take for instance `a = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0}}` with the rank 1, what should be the output?

Comment: {{1}} I think..

Comment: this works, but...:

ll = Table[MatrixRank[Take[mat, ii]], {ii, 1, Length[mat]}];
gde = Table[FirstPosition[ll, ii], {ii, 1, MatrixRank[mat]}] // 
   Flatten;
Rmat = mat[[gde]];

Rmat = Transpose[Rmat];
ll = Table[MatrixRank[Take[Rmat, ii]], {ii, 1, Length[Rmat]}];
gde = Table[FirstPosition[ll, ii], {ii, 1, MatrixRank[Rmat]}] // 
   Flatten;
Rmat = Rmat[[gde]];

Comment: Jelena, you write: ", I got bigger matrix from homogenous system of linear equations, it is overdetermined". The standard solution is: instead to solve  m.x==b, you solve: Transpose[m].m == Transpose[m].b This gives a least square solution.

Comment: thanks, but that was not my question.

Answer (score 2):

This might work.

```
a = RandomChoice[Alphabet[], {5, 5}];

(*add some extra rows*)
a = Insert[a, 2 a[[1]], 4];
a = Insert[a, 3 a[[2]], 6];

MatrixForm[a]
```

\begin{pmatrix}
 \text{f} & \text{s} & \text{j} & \text{v} & \text{p} \\
 \text{j} & \text{v} & \text{k} & \text{m} & \text{b} \\
 \text{m} & \text{v} & \text{i} & \text{h} & \text{n} \\
 2 \text{f} & 2 \text{s} & 2 \text{j} & 2 \text{v} & 2 \text{p} \\
 \text{z} & \text{e} & \text{k} & \text{n} & \text{x} \\
 3 \text{j} & 3 \text{v} & 3 \text{k} & 3 \text{m} & 3 \text{b} \\
 \text{i} & \text{n} & \text{l} & \text{d} & \text{o} \\
\end{pmatrix}

```
Dimensions[a]
MatrixRank[a]
```

> {7,5}

> 5

```
b = Transpose@RowReduce@Transpose@a;
c = a[[Position[b, 1][[All, 1]]]];
MatrixForm[c]
```

\begin{pmatrix}
 \text{f} & \text{s} & \text{j} & \text{v} & \text{p} \\
 \text{j} & \text{v} & \text{k} & \text{m} & \text{b} \\
 \text{m} & \text{v} & \text{i} & \text{h} & \text{n} \\
 \text{z} & \text{e} & \text{k} & \text{n} & \text{x} \\
 \text{i} & \text{n} & \text{l} & \text{d} & \text{o} \\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: thank but no :( sorry I don't know how to insert new lines..try with this example:
a = {{2 I A + 2 I B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     2, 2 G1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 I A + 2 I B}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 2 I A + 2 I B, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2 I A + 2 I B - G1 - G2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2 I A + 2 I B, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 G2, 2 I A + 2 I B, 
    0, 0, 0, 0}};

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a solution. My assumption is you want the candidate smaller matrix to have the same elements in the same order as the larger one, but with extra rows and columns removed. This generates all possible solutions.

Use your matrix in the comments

```
  a = {{2 I A + 2 I B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2 G1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 I A + 2 I B}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 I A + 2 I B, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 I A + 2 I B - G1 - G2, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 I A + 2 I B, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 G2, 2 I A + 2 I B, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Get the rank

```
 mr=MatrixRank@a
 (* 6 *)
```

Get the dimensions

```
 {rise, run} = Dimensions@a
```

Get all possible permutations of the indices

```
 rises = Subsets[Range[rise], {mr}];
 runs = Subsets[Range[run], {mr}];
```

Get all permutations of matrices

```
 matrices = Flatten[Outer[a[[#1, #2]] &, rises, runs, 1], 1];
```

There are lots of them

```
 Length@matrices
 (* 924 *)
```

Get just the ones that satisfy your requirement that they be full rank

```
 goodmatrices = Select[matrices, MatrixRank[#] == mr &];
```

Of which there are still quite a few

```
 Length@goodmatrices
 (* 64 *)
```

This can all be combined into a neat function.

Comment: thank you, it looks ok. my question was more if it can be done with rowreduce of some transformation already implemented in mathematica,  something like Sumit suggested. I know how to do it ...

Comment: You were never clear on exactly what you wanted, that the start matrix would be transformed into. It's still an open question.

Comment: let's say to reduce matrix by eliminating dependent columns and rows, but by using mathematica builtin functions, like rowreduce or something else. this is the way, and there are other, but I wonder is there something simpler:

ll = Table[MatrixRank[Take[mat, ii]], {ii, 1, Length[mat]}];
gde = Table[FirstPosition[ll, ii], {ii, 1, MatrixRank[mat]}] // 
   Flatten;
Rmat = mat[[gde]];

Rmat = Transpose[Rmat];
ll = Table[MatrixRank[Take[Rmat, ii]], {ii, 1, Length[Rmat]}];
gde = Table[FirstPosition[ll, ii], {ii, 1, MatrixRank[Rmat]}] // 
   Flatten;
Rmat = Rmat[[gde]];